# x64: Is there an INX instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, increment

From the page in the [Intel docs *"Introduction to x64 Assembly"*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/Introduction_to_x64_Assembly.pdf) you can see this code

```
Label: ; this is a label in assembly
 INX EAX ; increment eax
 LOOP Label ; decrement ECX, loop if not 0
```

Why do they say `INX` and not `INC`?

Comment: Can be a _typo_?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no INX instruction in the x86 instruction set. The instruction meant to be used here is the INC instruction. Since the X key is next to the C key on most keyboards this a simple mistake to make.

Without spending much time reading it, I would have to question the value of any sort introductory document that uses the LOOP instruction in an example.  There is rarely a good reason to the LOOP instruction in code being written today, or anytime in the last 25 years.

Comment: The examples using `loop` and `xchg` are one of the few bad parts of that guide.  When I looked over it a while ago (actually, [the HTML version](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly), not PDF), it looked good enough to add to the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), with a caveat [about `loop` sucking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).  I hadn't noticed the typo :P

Comment: i was 97% sure it was a typo, but with over 2,000 instructions knowing about 50 didn't give me much confidence.